# Clonning/Duplicating and filling data in Layout dynamically through JAVA from Firebase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to clone/Duplicate a linear_layout, through java from Firebase reatime-database.

[image]

I the screenshot I have a child history which contains user_id's and it's childs and so on. I want to put it dynamically in this layout.

[image]

I have statically copied the layout three times, but I want to make it dynamic, same as the size of the history table entries with current user id.

Also I do have a class User with getter setter and constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user ids under the `history` node and use them to add a `User` object to the database, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("history").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child("users").child(key);
            User user = new User(/* ... */); //Pass data to the constructor
            keyRef.setValue(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Hi Hafeez! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi Alex Mamo, yup it's helpful, but my main target of the question is how can i put it to the repeating XML dynamically, though your answer helped in retrieving data from firebase.

Comment: Good to hear that :) There was nothing specified in your question about "repeating XML dynamically" but this sounds basically as another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: "Clonning/Duplicating and filling data in Layout dynamically through JAVA from Firebase - Android" That's the question, do you really think you answered me to the point? Ok, if the community allow only questions, that should be answered in a single scenario, then help me out in repeating my xml layout, as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer, and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: It's up to you to decide if my answer was helpful, so you can accept it or not.

Comment: I am afraid, i can't, sorry... And thanks for your kind words!